# Python re.match - a successful match result for a digit is a letter?

Tags: python, regex

Some really odd behaviour I can’t work out with what should be a simple regex in Python 3.7...

I have a string `msg_data` which contains `event=mynode+button+0`.

If I use the pattern `r'^event=(?P<node>[\w-]{1,19})+(?P<interface>[\w-]{1,19})+` it works as expected - if I run `params = re.match(pattern, msg_data)` then `params.group('node') = "mynode"`, and `params.group('interface') = "button"`.  All fine so far.

However, I can't match the `0` at the end...

If I add `(?P<duration>[\d]+)` to the end of my pattern, I get no matches and hence `params = false`.  Same if I try `[0-9]` in the regex.  And it won't match even if I put a literal `0` in the pattern.

However, if I add `(?P<duration>[\w]+)` to the end of my pattern, it matches - but gives `params.group('duration') = "s"`!!

Note that if the `0` is a `1`, then it matches the letter `r` instead.

So the obvious question... what's going on?  I've got loads of other regex patterns matching numbers fine.  The `msg_data` string is coming from a http POST event, but is created as a 0 and prints as a 0 at all points elsewhere in the code.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this behaviour?  It's been driving me crazy for two days - a really simple regex that just doesn't match what it should.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `+` has the special meaning of "one or more instances of the previous". You need to escape to `\+` to match a literal `+`.

Comment: Please include a sample of the code in your question; it may have something to do with how you defined the regex.

Comment: Ah of course - @user2722968 that's right!  That's fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user2722968 for the answer - the basic error was not escaping the literal + in my pattern.

The impact was then slightly obscure, and I made a key mistake of not actually checking that `params.group('node')` and `params.group('interface')` were as expected.  Actually they weren't.  `params.group('node')` matched all except the last two characters in the first part of `msg_data` - then `params.group('interface')` matched the second-to-last, and `params.group('duration')` matched the last.  The reason for the `s` vs `r` distinction is that I had a number of buttons on the webpage, and tried different ones on various occasions (which all had different variations of `mynode`.  `r` and `s` corresponded to the last letter depending on which button I pressed - again, bad assumption on my part!

So great answer, thanks, but bad question on my part - too many assumptions of the "obvious", without checking.  My bad, lesson learnt  :(